# wsadmin AdminApp.install of a 23MB EAR is hanging

Tags: deployment, websphere, ear, wsadmin

I'm able to log into my local WAS 8 admin console and deploy a 23MB EAR with all of the defaults with no problems.  However, when I attempt to do the install using wsadmin and this Jython script...

```
AdminApp.install('C:\Development\MyApp\MyApp.ear')
AdminConfig.save()
```

... wsadmin just hangs.  I've been running this script right now for well over 10 minutes with my CPU at 70% on the java.exe process responsible for the deploy.

I would like to run my EAR deploys/undeploys using wsadmin if at all possible to bypass the need to log into the admin console.

Are there settings specific to wsadmin that I could tweak to make this deploy successful?

**EDIT I**
I tweaked my wsadmin call to launch like this (it gets called from a DOS command line...)

```
C:\Development\batch>call "C:\Development\WebSphere\WAS8.0\bin\wsadmin" -lang jython -conntype none -javaoption -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -f MyApp\MyAppDeploy.py
```

and now I'm getting java.lang.OutOfMemoryError...

```
Exception in thread "Bundle File Closer" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.close(Native Method)
java/lang/OutOfMemoryError
        at java/util/zip/ZipFile.close (Native Method)
        at java/util/zip/ZipFile.close (ZipFile.java:408)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/bundlefile/ZipBundleFile.close (ZipBundleFile.java:313)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/bundlefile/MRUBundleFileList.dispatchEvent (MRUBundleFileList.java:183)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/EventManager.dispatchEvent (EventManager.java:227)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/EventManager$EventThread.run (EventManager.java:337)
Exception in thread "Bundle File Closer"        at Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.OutOfMemoryErrorjava.lang.O
utOfMemoryError

        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:156  at )
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startjava.util.zip.ZipFile(.BundleContextImpl.java
:75Exception in thread "Thread-10" java/lang/OutOfMemoryError
1closejava.lang.OutOfMemoryError
        at java/util/zip/ZipFile.close (Native Method)
        at java/util/zip/ZipFile.close (ZipFile.java:408)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/bundlefile/ZipBundleFile.close (ZipBundleFile.java:313)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/baseadaptor/bundlefile/MRUBundleFileList.dispatchEvent (MRUBundleFileList.java:183)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/EventManager.dispatchEvent (EventManager.java:227)
        at org/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/EventManager$EventThread.run (EventManager.java:337)
        at java.nio.CharBuffer.wrap(CharBuffer.java:361)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:399)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:159)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:122)
        at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:500)
        at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:643)
        at com.ibm.jvm.io.ConsolePrintStream.print(ConsolePrintStream.java:java/lang/OutOfMemoryError
        at java/nio/CharBuffer.wrap (CharBuffer.java:361)
        at sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder$CharsetSE.implWrite (StreamEncoder.java:399)
        at sun/nio/cs/StreamEncoder.write (StreamEncoder.java:159)
        at java/io/OutputStreamWriter.write (OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
        at java/io/BufferedWriter.flushBuffer (BufferedWriter.java:122)
        at java/io/PrintStream.write (PrintStream.java:500)
        at java/io/PrintStream.print (PrintStream.java:643)
        at com/ibm/jvm/io/ConsolePrintStream.print (ConsolePrintStream.java:275)
        at java/io/PrintStream.append (PrintStream.java:1039)
        at java/io/PrintStream.append (PrintStream.java:51)
        at java/lang/StackTraceElement.appendTo (StackTraceElement.java:197)
        at java/lang/StackTraceElement.appendTo (StackTraceElement.java:217)
        at java/lang/StackTraceElement.appendTo (StackTraceElement.java:165)
        at java/lang/Throwable.printStackTrace (Throwable.java:375)
        at java/lang/Throwable.printStackTrace (Throwable.java:212)
        at java/lang/ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:779)
        at java/lang/ThreadGroup.uncaughtException (ThreadGroup.java:772)
        at java/lang/Thread.uncaughtException (Thread.java:1223)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following solved it for me.  This launched from the DOS command line on my PC.

```
call "C:\Development\WebSphere\WAS8.0\bin\wsadmin" -lang jython -javaoption -Xmx1024m -f %1
```